# Why I do not recieve emails sent in laravel at yahoo.com account?

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

In my Laravel 8 I use sendgrid for emails with account info in .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myaccount@gmail.com

MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD="XX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and emailing in control like :

```
Mail::to($new_user)->send(new UserRegistered($subject,
    $site_home_url,
    $new_user->email,
    $new_user->full_name,
    $confirm_url,
    $support_signature
));
```

where `UserRegistered` is `app/Mail/UserRegistered.php` file

and testing with several my email accounts I found that I recieve emails at all my accounts, except
yahoo.com.  Checking Spam folder I see it is empty : https://i.stack.imgur.com/x147I.jpg

I wonder why I do not receive emails at yahoo.com? any additive rules of yahoo.com?

Are there any debugging tools on Sendgrid side or Laravel?

Comment: try to change this:Mail::to($new_user->email)

Comment: Hint: `Mail::to($new_user->email)`

Comment: Sending using `smtp.sendgrid.net` for a Gmail account as the sender will fail many spam filters, as Gmail's SPF settings don't permit that as a valid sending server. If you want to send from a Gmail address, you're going to need to use Gmail's SMTP servers.

Comment: Are there some plugins/tools controlling Gmail's SPF settings  ? In my browser or in my account ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo You cannot manage Gmail's SPF records. It's simply not possible.